# How do i duplicate a KinematicBody2D in Godot? (C#)

Tags: c#, duplicates, game-development, godot

I'm trying to make a game where a player has to dodge constantly incoming, enemies. So I figured out that instead of just creating many many bodies, I could just duplicate them in a certain rate, and change the position of a duplicate. So I had to learn how to duplicate a body, I just took a player KinematicBody2D for now. I asked ChatGPT to do it for me because there was NOTHING in google, but I quickly came across errors.

Apparently, the "Player" node doesn't exist, which it DOES exist, I double checked (only typing in "Player" didn't work so I thought I could type a parent node its coming from, but no), and also another error I don't understand, here are the exact error messages:

`get_node: (Node not found "Game/player" (relative to "/root/Game/Player").)`

`void Player._Ready(): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Heres the code:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Player : KinematicBody2D
{
    [Export]
    public int Speed = 200;
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        KinematicBody2D OriginalBody = GetNode<KinematicBody2D>("Game/Player");
        KinematicBody2D CloneBody = OriginalBody.Duplicate() as KinematicBody2D;
        OriginalBody.GetParent().AddChild(CloneBody);
        Vector2 DuplicatePos = OriginalBody.Position - new Vector2(100, 0);
        CloneBody.Position = DuplicatePos;
    }

    public override void _Process(float delta)
    {
        var Motion = new Vector2();
        Motion.x = Input.GetActionStrength("move_right") - Input.GetActionStrength("move_left");
        Motion.y = Input.GetActionStrength("move_down") - Input.GetActionStrength("move_up");
        MoveAndCollide(Motion.Normalized() * Speed * delta);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error again:

> get_node: (Node not found "Game/player" (relative to "/root/Game/Player").)

It says that, relative to "/root/Game/Player" you are trying to get "Game/player". So the path you are trying to get is "/root/Game/Player/Game/player". And I bet there isn't a player there.

---

As far as I can tell the player you want to duplicate is the same object where your code is running.

Thus, you could - **but don't** - use `this.Duplicate()`.

*Don't.* Because the duplicate will do the same, and they won't stop duplicating until the process cannot chew more resources.

You need a way to control when and how many duplicates you make. Which suggest to use a different node to control the process.

---

Since you would be using a different node anyway. As alternative to duplicating, I want to encourage a *spawner*.

You are going to:

- Make a new scene with whatever you want to instantiate/spawn multiple times.
- Make a node with a script that loads and instantiates said scene, and adds the new instances to the scene tree.

You can, for example, export a `PackedScene` so you can set what scene to spawn form the editor:

```
[Export]
public PackedScene scene;
```

Then, from a method, when appropriate (e.g. in a signal handler, perhaps from a timer), you instance said scene:

```
var new_instance = scene.Instance();
```

And add it to the scene tree (in this case as a child of the spawner):

```
AddChild(new_instance);
```

You could, of course, add it as a child of a different node, and you could set its properties to whatever you need (including changing its position).